# PLSQL - trunc function - booking due within 24 hours

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I was just wondering how would I go about checking to see if, for example, a booking is due within 24 hours?

My bookings table will have the important fields that may help in finding the solution: studiono, title, date, time, hour

At the moment, I have tried the following:

```
select StudioNo 
from Bookings 
where sysdate - "DATE" <1 
and "TIME" - trunc("Time") + trunc(systimestamp) > systimestamp;
```

However,  I don't think this works. Am I doing this correctly?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing what your database structure is:

```
select StudioNo 
from Bookings 
where to_date(date || time, 'dd-mon-yyyyhh24:mi:ss') < sysdate +1
and to_date(date || time, 'dd-mon-yyyyhh24:mi:ss') > sysdate
```

basically, create a single date/time field from your 2 seperate date and time columns (which I'm assuming here are strings), and then compare that to sysdate + 1

Comment: Unless old booking are deleted, you may also want to have a `> sysdate` condition in there.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, is there any particular reason why your `Bookings` table has separate columns for date and time? The Oracle datatype `DATE` will include both of these in a single column. This will then make the required query much more straight forward:

```
SELECT StudioNo 
FROM Bookings 
WHERE BookingDate BETWEEN SYSDATE AND SYSDATE+1;
```

Comment: Unless old booking are deleted, you may also want to have a `> sysdate` condition in there

Comment: @Dems - I already spotted this thanks, updated to use `BETWEEN`

Comment: Actually, the original question said the criteria was "due within 24 hours".  I interpret that to mean up to 24 hours before *right now* and 24 hours after *right now*.  So, it seems to me, the correct predicate would be:
WHERE BookingDate BETWEEN SYSDATE-1 and SYSDATE+1;

Comment: @MarkBobak - I'm inclined to disagree, I can see a sort of logic to what you're saying, but in practice when someone says "due within", they are invariably referring to a future event. The word "due" in fact implies that it has not already taken place.